# Access script element using WATIR

Tags: watir

I have the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                <!-- /$('.mc_col_header tr:odd').css({'background':'#faf8f8'}); -->
                <!-- /$('.mc_col_header tr:even').css({'background':'#f5f0f0'}); -->
                <!-- /$('.mc_col_header tr:first').css({'background':'#fff'}); -->
                <!-- /$('.mc_col_header td',$('.mc_col_header tr:first')).css({'background':'#fff'}); -->
                <!-- /paginator -->
                paginatorPosition = 'bottom';
                separator = ' ';
                paginatorStyle = 2;
                enablePageOfOption = false;
                enableSelectNoItems = false;
                firstPageSymbol = "First";
                nextPageSymbol = "Next »";
                previousPageSymbol = "« Prev";
                lastPageSymbol = "Last";
                itemsPerPage = parseInt($('input.questions_per_page').attr('value'));
                $('.questions').pagination();
                });
              </script>
```

And I would like to access the following using Watir:

```
nextPageSymbol = "Next »";
```

How do I implement it?

Comment: We need HMTL that the JavaScript you have provided generates. Use Firebug or similar tool, and search for `Next »` in generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by finding the element using Firebug (thanks!), and created a link access using xpath:

```
@browser.link(:xpath, 'the_path_generated').click
```